# OpenCV: setting inside of irregularly shaped contour to a color

Tags: python, opencv, numpy

I have an image and I am using OpenCV to find the contours within that image.  For example:

```
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(image, cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
```

Each contour that get returned is sometimes very irregularly shaped.  For example, the return of one of them is:

```
contour = [[[34  4]]
[[35  3]]
[[36  4]]
[[36 11]]
[[35 12]]
[[34 11]]
[[34  6]]
[[33  6]]
[[32  5]]
[[33  4]]]
```

I would like to set the interior of this contour to a specific color.  I've tried using cv2.BoundingRect to get the bounding rectangle of this contour, and then using that to set the color, however, I would like a more precise way to do this using the actual contour.

Is there a straightforward way to do this through a function that OpenCV provides, or through NumPy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `cv2.drawContours()` function with `lineType = -1` flag ([Docs](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/drawing_functions.html?highlight=drawcontours#drawcontours))

eg : **cv2.drawContours(img,[cnt],0,color,-1)** # for filling inside a specific contour

or

**cv2.drawContours(img,contours,-1,color,-1)** # to fill inside all the contours in a single step

For more details, visit : [Contours -1 : Getting Started](http://opencvpython.blogspot.com/2012/06/hi-this-article-is-tutorial-which-try.html)